# Retrieving list member information from mailchimp - limited fields returned - PHP

Tags: php, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Trying to synchronize member information from Mailchimp to our local DB. We are able to request the information, but we get back only the FNAME, LNAME and BIRTHDAY fields. We are calling the function:

```
$mailchimp_v3_service->get_list_members($list_id, $count, $offset)
```

And are getting back a list of stdClass objects:

```
stdClass Object
(
  [id] => <an id>
  [email_address] => <an email>
  [unique_email_id] => <a unique email id>
  [status] => unsubscribed
  [merge_fields] => stdClass Object
    (
        [FNAME] => Testable
        [LNAME] => Contact
        [BIRTHDAY] => 
    )
)
```

Looking at the function call inside the Mailchimp code (MailchimpV3Service.php), it looks like it is requesting more/different fields than we are getting:

fields=members.id,members.email_address,members.status,members.unique_email_id,members.merge_fields.LNAME,members.merge_fields.FNAME,,members.merge_fields.PHONE

It looks like the function is requesting PHONE, and not requesting BIRTHDAY.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you link the library you're using?

Comment: One correction - the MailchimpV3Service.php is our code, the call being made inside there uses curl to make the GET request for: "lists/".$list_id."/members?fields=members.id,members.email_address,members.status,members.unique_email_id,members.merge_fields.LNAME,members.merge_fields.FNAME,,members.merge_fields.PHONE

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the exact cURL request you make?

Comment: I don't know how this will come out in the comment box, but we are using the php curl library function. The URL we are hitting is:     https://us16.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<list id>/members?fields=members.id,members.email_address,members.status,members.unique_email_id,members.merge_fields.LNAME,members.merge_fields.FNAME,members.merge_fields.PHONE&count=100&offset=0

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the issue - our support team was adding a phone number field to only certain accounts, depending on who needed it. If there is no phone field, it's just not returned. Lesson learned: check your "List fields and *|MERGE|* tags" section. 8-/